# Flutter - How to add a button on the middle of a paragraph

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I want to add a `TextButton` in the middle of a paragraph in a `Text` widget. Similarly when writing a paragraph and want to add a button to let users route to that screen to get the desired information about something. How could I do that?

Thank you

Comment: RichText widget will help. What is the condition on generating button while writing a paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `RichText` to make your works clickable.
you can use like this :

```
RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(text: 'By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our '),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: 'Terms of Service',
                          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                            ..onTap = () {
                              print('Terms of Service"');
                            }),
                      TextSpan(text: ' and that you have read our '),
                      TextSpan(
                          text: 'Privacy Policy',
                          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                            ..onTap = () {
                              print('Privacy Policy"');
                            }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Thank you man this is really helpful I really appreciate it.